# sql server change PK type from int to uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql-server

I need to change the type of my primary key column on a table from int to guid. The database already has data that I don't want to lose, and there are foreign keys to consider. Is there a painless way to do this or do I have to manually do it through a big a** script?:) I would appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  I'm currently attempting the opposite...

Comment: I, too, would rather recommend **not** doing that - any particular reason for this??

Comment: I need to do it because I'm setting up merge replication with several subscriber servers, and I don't want my row id's to change due to synchronization. Also, since merge replication automatically adds a guid column in all tables if you dont allready have a guid PK col, an aditional int id colun is redundant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to do it the hard way, using scripts:

0) get in single user mode
1) add the new GUID column to the main table, and populate it.
2) add the new FK column to each child table and populate them with an UPDATE FROM

```
UPDATE c
    SET FKcolumn=p.NewGuid
    FROM ChildTable             c
        INNER JOIN ParentTable  p ON p.OldIntID=c.OldIntId
```

3) drop the existing int FKs
4) drop the old int columns
5) add the new FKs on the guid column
6) get out of single user mode

you should be able to get SQL Server Management studio to generate the scripts for adding and dropping the columns and keys.  Just make the changes in SSMS and click on the "Generate Change Script" toolbar icon and you can cut and paste the code to a text file.

Comment: WOW You are genius !!

Answer (score 1):

1. Use option "Generate scripts" on your database in order to create "DROP/CREATE CONSTRAINT and INDEXES" (use advanced button to tune wizard).
   Run portion of created SQL script to drop indexes and constraints.
2. Create one helper function and procedure as follows:

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GuidFromHash]
   (
       @Input nvarchar(MAX)
   )
   RETURNS nvarchar(MAX)
   AS
   BEGIN
       RETURN LOWER(SUBSTRING(@Input, 1,8)+'-'+SUBSTRING(@Input, 9,4)+'-'+SUBSTRING(@Input, 13,4)+'-'+SUBSTRING(@Input, 17,4)+'-'+SUBSTRING(@Input, 21,12))
   END

   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[bigIntToGuid]
   (
       @table varchar(50),
       @column varchar(50)
   )
   AS
   DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

   SET @SQL='UPDATE @Table SET @Column=dbo.HashToGuid(''cc''+CONVERT(VARCHAR, HASHBYTES(''MD5'',LTRIM(@Column)),2))'
   SET @SQL=REPLACE(@SQL,'@Table',@Table)
   SET @SQL=REPLACE(@SQL,'@Column',@Column)
   EXEC(@SQL)

   SET @SQL='SELECT * FROM @Table'
   SET @SQL=REPLACE(@SQL,'@Table',@Table)
   SET @SQL=REPLACE(@SQL,'@Column',@Column)
   EXEC(@SQL)
   ```
3. Now comes the manual work for every table:

   1. Open table in designer (SQL Management Studio or other tool)
   2. Change bigint type of column to VARCHAR(50)
   3. Execute "EXEC bigIntToGuid 'myTable','myBigIntColumn'
   4. Back to table designer change column type to "uniqueidentifier"
   5. Optionally you can add default value: newid(), and/or set column as primary key
4. Open your sql generated script created in step 1
5. Select only portion of the script for constraint and index creation, and execute it

This approach ensures converting int to guid and keep data integrity.

Comment: There's a typo in the SQL snippet: HashToGuid should read GuidFromHash, or the function name should be changed to HashToGuid.